# Can I cash out a French check in South Korea?

Tags: check, france, south-korea

I have a check written in French emitted in France by a French bank. Can I cash it out somewhere in South Korea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

If you have a french bank account you can probably mail it to your bank.